# Computer languages are considered as finite sets, and mathematically set operations can be performed on them

Tags: compiler-construction, lexical-analysis

I am reading about Compiler Design - Lexical Analysis and I came across this sentence. I didn't get it.
What set operations can be performed on Computer Languages and how exactly? How does union, intersection etc look like in a computer language, someone please explain

Here's the link from where I am reading:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compiler_design/compiler_design_lexical_analysis.htm

Comment: I didn't read the whole article, but in the paragraph that your quote is from, there is not a single sentence that doesn't contain at least falsehood. I strongly recommend that you stop reading that tutorial and look for a better one. Programming languages aren't finite sets - they're infinite sets (plus semantics). And while regular expression can indeed match finite languages, they're almost always used to match infinite ones.

Comment: And there are almost no programming languages that can be matched by regular expressions - regular expressions are only used for lexing not to match the whole language. So saying "Programming languages are finite sets, so they can be described by regular expressions" is wrong in a multitude of ways.

Comment: And while you can perform set operations like union and intersection on programming languages (or at least on their syntax), it is almost never meaningful to do so (with the possible exception of calling one language a sub- or superset of another). Certainly not in the context of compiler design. So that's another thing that makes no sense in that article.

Comment: I agree with @sepp2k, learning about parsing from internet sites is not only bad, for every bad habit you pick up from a site it will take you about 5x or more as much time to unlearn the bad habit and pick up the correct way. I made same mistake trying to use StackOverflow to learn about DCGs. Lost about 2 years of time because of it.

Comment: I gave this a down vote, not because the question is wrong, but because it is not something others should find and learn from. An upvote or no vote would agree that this is a question of value; I don't see it that way. Sorry for the down-vote, nothing personal.

Comment: Also you should copy the relevant sections from the link into here. I had to read a few pages just to get to what you are referencing. The only reason I even bothered to look beyond a minute of time was that this was related to parsing which is a favorite topic of mine.

Answer (score 1):

The only sense in which computer languages are *finite* sets is the practical limitation that we live in a finite universe. In this finite universe, everything has a limit. That's probably a useful perspective for many practical problems but it doesn't help understand mathematical models. (I'm not sure how useful your source is, either. Personally, I'd suggest one of the traditional textbooks.)

The framework of formal language theory defines a language as an infinite set of finite strings. That set is simply the set of valid strings -- in this case computer programs.

The intersection of two languages (considered as sets of valid sentences) is just like any other set intersection: it consists of all things which are in both sets. Similarly, the union of two languages is theset of strings which are in at least one of the languages.

As examples, we could (in theory) construct the set of programs which are both valid C and which contain the identifier `future`. Or the set of strings which are either JSON or XML. And so on.